configure hashi vault LDAP authentication in docker container image
I’m very new to Vault. I’m trying to add LDAP authentication to config.hcl, but can’t figure out how to do it. I’m trying to make it so LDAP is preconfigured when the Docker container starts so I don’t have to login and manully configure it via the web interface each time the docker container starts.
For example, I’d like to have following equivalent done when docker contailer starts:
# Enable LDAP authentication
vault auth enable ldap

# Configure LDAP authentication
vault write auth/ldap/config \
    url="ldaps://ldap.example.com" \
    binddn="cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com" \
    bindpass="yourpassword" \
    userattr="uid" \
    userdn="ou=People,dc=example,dc=com" \
    groupdn="ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com" \
    groupfilter="(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={{.Username}}))" \
    groupattr="cn"

